# ¿Cómo puedo concatenar dentro de un getElementById?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que sucede es que no puedo cambiar el color de fondo de un elemento `td`, ya que el valor cambia dependiendo de una variable global.

Tengo lo siguiente código

```
function rellenarConColor(){
    var hola = "''"+texto+"''";
    document.getElementById(hola).bgColor='#50bfff'; 
}
```

En `console.log(hola);` //el resultado es `'A5874'` pero no logra cambiarse y si he validado ya que el id de mi elemento `tr` si sea ese, pero no logro hacerlo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar tu código HTML por fa? Así con eso que pones no es suficiente contexto como para responder la pregunta

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo que es

```
document.getElementById(hola).style.backgroundColor = "#50bfff";
```

Ejemplo: (también en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skdr780e/))

```js
function cambiaColor(){
  document.getElementById("azul").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
}
```

```css
#verde{
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

#azul{
  background-color: #0000FF
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="verde">TD verde</td>
    <td id="azul">TD azul</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="cambiaColor()">Click me</button>
```